# OpenCV warpAffine unexpected behavior: Repeated Pattern when not using INTER_NEAREST

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform

I have a matrix cv::Mat CorrespondenceMap where each element contains its own index. I then use these indexes to reconstruct the transformed image.

When I perform the operation directly on the image data I get the correct first visual. If I do it through the correspondence map it only works when I set to INTER_NEAREST otherwise I get the image shown

```
std::vector<int> cmap(width*height);
std::iota (std::begin(cmap), std::end(cmap), 0); // Fill with incrementing ints
cv::Mat cmapMat(height, width, CV_32SC1, cmap.data());
cmapMat.convertTo(cmapMat, CV_64F);
cv::warpAffine(source, transformedimage, lkParams.rowRange(0,2), source.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, -1);
cmapMat.convertTo(cmapMat, CV_32S, 1, 0.5);
```

[image: directly on image]

[image]

Comment: How do you expect this interpolation of 1D indices to work? Especially in the vertical direction. E.g. in a 20x20 image, iterpolate the index between points in 10th column and rows 1 and 2.

Comment: Ah yes, I had not considered the vert direction

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to make the correspondence map would be. Using nearest works somewhat well but does not seem to transform as well as doing directly on image data.

Comment: Since you're working in 2 dimensions, then perhaps it needs to have 2 channels? So you encode (X,Y) position of each point.

Comment: That should do the trick. Thank you!